# ZeroBrane - not running on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, coronasdk, zerobrane

I started using ZeroBrane studio in ubuntu for my Corona projects. For Corona to work i am using wine in ubuntu. After path to Corona SDK configuration i tried to run a simple project for testing purposes. But i got the following annoying error. Please see the image below in the link for more details.

the error:
"path:to:project/YES was not found"
So what is this "YES"? I haven't any file or folder called "YES" in my project directory? How is it looking for it?

http://s21.postimg.org/3s5dwa5c7/Screenshot_from_2015_04_14_08_06_34.png

Comment: Check the output console. YES seems to be an argument passed when launching Corona Simulator, one that isn't valid. Not sure where is it being set, though try to remove it and keep only "no-console -debug".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be a problem running under Wine as ZeroBrane Studio was mis-detecting its environment. It has been [fixed](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/commit/68b7272403b72d9a579a8750dd8b319116cc883b) in [v1.10](http://studio.zerobrane.com).